# How can I remove all console.logs using VIM

Tags: vim, console.log

I'm able to delete all console.logs in a file using `g/log/d`, but I'm trying to find a way to remove all of them from all files in a directory.  I tried `:argdo g/log/d | update` but to be honest, I'm not at all sure how to accomplish this.

https://thepugautomatic.com/2014/12/vim-global/

@Harish your answer works great when i tested it on a basic project, but there are strange side effects when running this on my react projects.

```
import axios from 'axios' //write user autentication actions 
import {serverURL} from './config'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; 

export const signUp = async (user) => axios.post(`${serverURL}/api/signup`,  user)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data    
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return {error:true, message: error.response.data.message}          
    });

export const logIn = async (user) => axios.post(`${serverURL}/api/login`,  user)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return {error:true, message: error.response.data.message}    
    });

export const logOut = async () => axios.post(`${serverURL}/api/logOut`)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return {error:true, message: error.response.data.message}
    });

export const loggedIn = async () => axios.get(`${serverURL}/api/loggedin`)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return {error:true, message: error.response.data.message}
    });
```

turns into:

```
import axios from 'axios' //write user autentication actions 
import {serverURL} from './config'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; 

export const signUp = async (user) => axios.post(`${serverURL}/api/signup`,  user)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data    
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return {error:true, message: error.response.data.message}          
    });

    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return {error:true, message: error.response.data.message}    
    });

    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return {error:true, message: error.response.data.message}
    });

    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return {error:true, message: error.response.data.message}
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to set `args` to files you want to update first and then call `argdo`.

```
:args ./*.js
```

above will select all the javascript files in the current directory. If the current directory has sub-directories and you want to select files recursively you could use

```
:args **/*.js
```

After setting the args you can call the `global` command using `argdo`

```
:argdo g/log/d | update
```

Comment: Thanks works great on simple project, but there's a strange side effect when running this on my react projects.  See above.

Comment: That's because we are targetting the pattern `log`, instead match the pattern `console\.log` to remove only the `console.log` statements. `:argdo g/console\.log/d | update`